# Create progress bar in bash

Tags: bash

How can I create a progress bar with bash?

This is my script :

```
#!/bin/bash
 pass='number1 number12 number13 number14 number15 number16'
 chk='number14'
 for i in $pass ; do
   if [ "$i" == "$chk" ]; then
     echo ' Found ^_^'
   else
     echo 'loading 50%'
   fi
 done
```

I want to replace `echo 'loading 50%'` with anything to create an progress bar.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [dialog](http://invisible-island.net/dialog/) *library*.

There is a simple [gauge widget](http://invisible-island.net/dialog/dialog-figures.html#demo_gauge) that could fit your needs.

For example:

```
( 
  echo 12 ; 
  sleep 2 ; 
  echo 34 ; 
  sleep 2 ; 
  echo "XXX" ;
  echo "working for you" ; 
  echo "XXX" ; 
  echo 50 ; 
  sleep 5 ; 
  echo 95 ; 
  sleep 1 ; 
  echo 100 ;
) | dialog --gauge "some progress" 6 50
```

Most distributions have the package ready to install (via the package manager).

Comment: Sorry , This is not all what i need , i need to see very simple progress bar in the terminal , Not GUI windows or dialog , For example :       `[ ###########--------------] 52%`

Comment: @Programmer Sorry, I do not understand the difference. It is a full screen progress bar in the terminal, with comments, title and color schemas. Has it too many features?

Comment: No but i want to create a progress bar that made by text as in the example above

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like that? The line with "Found" and regardless of that continuing the loop is not fine but I don't know what you wanna do there.

```
#!/bin/bash
pass='number1 number12 number13 number14 number15 number16'
chk='number14'
max=0
for i in $pass ; do
    let max=$max+1
done
index=0
strdone="#########################"
strtodo="-------------------------"
for i in $pass ; do
    let index=$index+1
    if [ "$i" == "$chk" ]; then
        echo ""
        echo ' Found ^_^'
    else
        lendone=$((index * ${#strdone} / max))
        let lentodo=${#strdone}-$lendone
        percent=$((index * 100 / max))
        echo -ne "[#${strdone:0:$lendone}${strtodo:0:$lentodo}] $percent%\r"
    fi
    sleep 1
done
echo ""
```

Output will be at the end:

```
[#############-------------] 50%
 Found ^_^
[##########################] 100%
```